# Update-alternatives does not update all Java symlinks

Tags: redhat, java, update-alternatives

I'm getting some strange behavior from update-alternatives on RHEL 7.9 when I have Amazon Correto Java 11 and the normal Java 1.8.0 both installed. When Correto is selected as the default, this is the content of /etc/alternatives:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 jaotc -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jaotc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Feb 27 15:09 jar -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Feb 27 15:09 jar.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jar.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Feb 27 15:09 jarsigner -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jarsigner
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57 Feb 27 15:09 jarsigner.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jarsigner.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Feb 27 15:43 java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Feb 27 15:43 java.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/java.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Feb 27 15:09 java_sdk -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Feb 27 15:09 javac.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/javac.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Feb 27 15:09 javadoc -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/javadoc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Feb 27 15:09 javadoc.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/javadoc.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 javap -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/javap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Feb 27 15:09 javap.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/javap.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Feb 27 15:09 jcmd -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jcmd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Feb 27 15:09 jcmd.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jcmd.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 Feb 27 15:09 jconsole -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jconsole
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 56 Feb 27 15:09 jconsole.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jconsole.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Feb 27 15:09 jdb -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Feb 27 15:09 jdb.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jdb.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Feb 27 15:09 jdeprscan -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jdeprscan
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 jdeps -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jdeps
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Feb 27 15:09 jdeps.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jdeps.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 jhsdb -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jhsdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Feb 27 15:09 jimage -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jimage
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 jinfo -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jinfo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Feb 27 15:09 jinfo.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jinfo.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Feb 27 15:43 jjs -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jjs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Feb 27 15:43 jjs.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jjs.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 jlink -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jlink
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Feb 27 15:09 jmap -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jmap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Feb 27 15:09 jmap.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jmap.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Feb 27 15:09 jmod -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Feb 27 15:09 jps -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jps
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Feb 27 15:09 jps.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jps.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Feb 27 15:43 jre -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 64 Feb 27 15:08 jre_1.8.0 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 64 Feb 27 15:08 jre_1.8.0_exports -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Feb 27 15:08 jre_1.8.0_openjdk -> /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 68 Feb 27 15:08 jre_1.8.0_openjdk_exports -> /usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 64 Feb 27 15:08 jre_openjdk -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 64 Feb 27 15:08 jre_openjdk_exports -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Feb 27 15:09 jrunscript -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jrunscript
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 Feb 27 15:09 jrunscript.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jrunscript.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Feb 27 15:09 jshell -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jshell
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Feb 27 15:09 jstack -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jstack
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Feb 27 15:09 jstack.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jstack.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 jstat -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jstat
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Feb 27 15:09 jstat.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jstat.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Feb 27 15:09 jstatd -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jstatd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Feb 27 15:09 jstatd.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jstatd.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Feb 27 15:43 keytool -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/keytool
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Feb 27 15:43 keytool.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/keytool.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Feb 27 14:55 ld -> /usr/bin/ld.bfd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Feb 27 14:54 libnssckbi.so.x86_64 -> /usr/lib64/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Feb 27 15:43 pack200 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/pack200
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Feb 27 15:43 pack200.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/pack200.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Feb 27 15:09 rmic -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/rmic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Feb 27 15:09 rmic.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/rmic.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Feb 27 15:43 rmid -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/rmid
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Feb 27 15:43 rmid.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/rmid.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Feb 27 15:43 rmiregistry -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/rmiregistry
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Feb 27 15:43 rmiregistry.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/rmiregistry.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Feb 27 15:09 serialver -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/serialver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57 Feb 27 15:09 serialver.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/serialver.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Feb 27 15:43 unpack200 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/unpack200
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57 Feb 27 15:43 unpack200.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/unpack200.1"
```

When I select Java 8, I get this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 77 Feb 27 16:00 alt-java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/alt-java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 81 Feb 27 16:00 alt-java.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/alt-java-java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 jaotc -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jaotc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Feb 27 15:09 jar -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Feb 27 15:09 jar.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jar.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Feb 27 15:09 jarsigner -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jarsigner
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57 Feb 27 15:09 jarsigner.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jarsigner.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 73 Feb 27 16:00 java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 77 Feb 27 16:00 java.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/java-java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Feb 27 15:09 java_sdk -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Feb 27 15:09 javac.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/javac.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Feb 27 15:09 javadoc -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/javadoc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Feb 27 15:09 javadoc.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/javadoc.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 javap -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/javap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Feb 27 15:09 javap.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/javap.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Feb 27 15:09 jcmd -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jcmd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Feb 27 15:09 jcmd.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jcmd.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 Feb 27 15:09 jconsole -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jconsole
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 56 Feb 27 15:09 jconsole.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jconsole.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Feb 27 15:09 jdb -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Feb 27 15:09 jdb.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jdb.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Feb 27 15:09 jdeprscan -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jdeprscan
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 jdeps -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jdeps
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Feb 27 15:09 jdeps.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jdeps.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 jhsdb -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jhsdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Feb 27 15:09 jimage -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jimage
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 jinfo -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jinfo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Feb 27 15:09 jinfo.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jinfo.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 72 Feb 27 16:00 jjs -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/jjs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 76 Feb 27 16:00 jjs.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/jjs-java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 jlink -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jlink
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Feb 27 15:09 jmap -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jmap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Feb 27 15:09 jmap.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jmap.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Feb 27 15:09 jmod -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Feb 27 15:09 jps -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jps
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Feb 27 15:09 jps.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jps.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 64 Feb 27 16:00 jre -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 64 Feb 27 15:08 jre_1.8.0 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 64 Feb 27 15:08 jre_1.8.0_exports -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Feb 27 15:08 jre_1.8.0_openjdk -> /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 68 Feb 27 15:08 jre_1.8.0_openjdk_exports -> /usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 67 Feb 27 16:00 jre_exports -> /usr/lib/jvm-exports/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 64 Feb 27 15:08 jre_openjdk -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 64 Feb 27 15:08 jre_openjdk_exports -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Feb 27 15:09 jrunscript -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jrunscript
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 Feb 27 15:09 jrunscript.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jrunscript.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Feb 27 15:09 jshell -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jshell
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Feb 27 15:09 jstack -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jstack
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Feb 27 15:09 jstack.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jstack.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 27 15:09 jstat -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jstat
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Feb 27 15:09 jstat.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jstat.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Feb 27 15:09 jstatd -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/jstatd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Feb 27 15:09 jstatd.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/jstatd.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 76 Feb 27 16:00 keytool -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/keytool
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 80 Feb 27 16:00 keytool.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/keytool-java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Feb 27 14:55 ld -> /usr/bin/ld.bfd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Feb 27 14:54 libnssckbi.so.x86_64 -> /usr/lib64/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 73 Feb 27 16:00 orbd -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/orbd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 77 Feb 27 16:00 orbd.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/orbd-java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 76 Feb 27 16:00 pack200 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/pack200
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 80 Feb 27 16:00 pack200.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/pack200-java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 79 Feb 27 16:00 policytool -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/policytool
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 83 Feb 27 16:00 policytool.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/policytool-java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Feb 27 15:09 rmic -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/rmic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Feb 27 15:09 rmic.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/rmic.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 73 Feb 27 16:00 rmid -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/rmid
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 77 Feb 27 16:00 rmid.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/rmid-java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 80 Feb 27 16:00 rmiregistry -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/rmiregistry
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 84 Feb 27 16:00 rmiregistry.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/rmiregistry-java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Feb 27 15:09 serialver -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/serialver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57 Feb 27 15:09 serialver.1 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/man/man1/serialver.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 79 Feb 27 16:00 servertool -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/servertool
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 83 Feb 27 16:00 servertool.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/servertool-java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 78 Feb 27 16:00 tnameserv -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/tnameserv
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 82 Feb 27 16:00 tnameserv.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/tnameserv-java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 78 Feb 27 16:00 unpack200 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/unpack200
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 82 Feb 27 16:00 unpack200.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/unpack200-java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.el7_9.x86_64.1.gz
```

Notice that the location of javac and other tools has not changed and a number of the links are highlighted in red, which I assume means they are now broken. ???

I have a feeling I am missing something that should be obvious. Any help?